# Electronic filter: simplifying expression with integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, laplace-transform

I've come across a generalised notch filter in an academic paper. The values $x_{f} and y_{f} $ are time varying values $x_{f}(t)$ and $y_{f}(t)$,

The equation of the filter block is expressed as follows, where $y_{f}$ is the output of the filter.
$$y_{f}(t) = \zeta_{m}\begin{bmatrix} \sin(\Omega t) & \cos(\Omega t)  \end{bmatrix} \int \begin{bmatrix} x_{f}(t)\sin(\Omega t)\\ x_{f}(t)\cos(\Omega t)  \end{bmatrix} dt $$

This equation evaluates to:
$$y_{f}(t) = \zeta_{m}\left[\sin(\Omega t)\int x_{f}(t) \sin(\Omega t)dt + \cos(\Omega t)\int x_{f}(t) \cos(\Omega t)] dt \right]$$

The authors then simplify this down to:
$$\frac{d^2y_{f}(t)}{dt^2} + \Omega^2y_{f} = \zeta_{m} \frac{dx_{f}(t)}{dt}$$

I just wonder how this result was obtained? How do the authors get rid of the sine and cosine terms? Was this done through Laplace transforms and convolution? Or am I missing an integration by parts simplification?

Comment: As a clarification, can you confirm that there is convolution in the expression? Right now, as written, there is no convolution.

Comment: There is no convolution in the expression

Answer (score 1):

There is convolution happening but it is a bit hard to see. Let me rewrite your expression with a different integration variable,

$$
y_f(t) = \zeta_m
\left[
\sin(\Omega t) \int_0^t x_f(\tau) \sin(\Omega\tau) d\tau
+ 
\cos(\Omega t) \int_0^t x_f(\tau) \cos(\Omega\tau) d\tau
\right]
$$

Bring the $\sin$ and $\cos$ in and put together the integrals to get,

$$
y_f(t) = \zeta_m
\int_0^t
x_f(\tau) \sin(\Omega t)  \sin(\Omega\tau)
+ 
 x_f(\tau) \cos(\Omega t) \cos(\Omega\tau) d\tau
$$

Use $\cos$ addition rule to get,

$$
y_f(t) = \zeta_m
\int_0^t
x_f(\tau) \cos(\Omega(t - \tau)) d\tau
$$

from which we can immediately compute the Laplace transform,

$$
Y_f(s) = \zeta_m \frac{s}{s^2 + \Omega^2} X_f(s)
$$

and the ODE follows from rewriting this as,

$$(s^2 + \Omega^2) Y_f(s) = \zeta_m s X_f(s).$$